# Phaser tint property turning black on some Sprites

Tags: path-finding, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a A* pathfinder and I'm testing it with a simple grid on Phaser but for some cells (third row & column) `tint` instead of setting "green" color for frontier cells they turn black :\

I reduced it as much as I could but I can't find why it's happening. In line 80 I added a comment showing the line that turns the cell black.

https://jsfiddle.net/amatiasq/emkxqpmf/

Generated pattern is really weird and it's always the same...

[image: Black ones are the bug]

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was not on `tilt` operation but on line 69 where `neighbour.parent` was assigned to the current cell.

Turns out `Sprite.parent` is a [phaser readonly property](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Sprite.html#parent). Replacing `parent` with any other property makes it work.